# Relationship between tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, relationship

I have two tables in a SQL Server 2008 database

- `Courses - CourseID[PK], CourseName, UnivID[Foreign Key]` // can have more than one values
- `University UnivID[PK], UnivName, AvailableCourse[foriegn key ]` //can have many courses

Now, one course can be available in more than one university and also one university can have many courses.

So how can I relate these two tables? I want to avoid comma separated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a many to many relationship. You'll find lots of articles online. Essentially you take UniversityId out of the courses table and create another table UniversityCourse with columns UniversityId and CourseId. This represents which courses are given by which universities.

There's a great [writeup with examples here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php).

Comment: How to maintain the UniversityCourse table, can u please give the sample of these three tables ?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need an "intermediate" or "link" table that contains both primary keys:

```
University_Course (UnivID, CourseID)
```

By adding rows into that table, you can link any number of universities with any number of courses.

- `University_Course.UnivID` is a foreign key to `University.UnivID`
- `University_Course.CourseID` is a foreign key to `Courses.CourseID`

Comment: can I create composite key constraint on University_Course Table to avoid duplicate records ?